# imported avi is jerky after cycles render in 2.92 / material preview in viewport is smooth

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, image

edited: thx blunder

i am trying to import an existing AVI. with "import image as plane".
everything looks fine in the viewport.

but it looks jerky as hell in the final render. but its limited to the imported AVI. Everything else looks smooth.

it looks like he is rendering the same frame of the avi-slideshow for 6-7 frames in the final-render. and on frame 8 he continuous to render the avi with frame 8.

so the "frame-pattern" would look like (1,1,1,1,1,1,7,8,9) instead of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) creating a "hick up / lag" every 20 to 30 frames - maybe.

Problem only occurs in cycles render (but i have to use cycles - eevee#s object emission shader doesnt light up textures of other objects - but this is mandatory for my project)

i tried to change the frame rate but have no idea what else i could try.
i'm very sorry for my broken english. and hope that someone who can help understand what i was writing.
thanks in advance and for all the other things i already have learned.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is a Q&A site, not a classic forum like https://blenderartists.org/. You don't need to introduce yourself, just focus on the question...but nice to meet you :-)

Comment: Try using an image sequence instead of the avi. The avi has to be decoded for the viewport and the material so this can cause issues.

Comment: Nice, don´t know if that´s exactly what you meant but my workaround now is:
New project - Import the original avi through video sequencer and rendered it as image sequence (jpg).
switched to my project and import the rendered image sequence "as plane" and voilà.
now it is a bit laggy in the viewport. but at least the final render is smooth. thank you!